# Windows Store App: Soft-Keyboard moves flyout and hides the focused TextBox: How to prevent this "clever" behavior?

Tags: windows-store-apps, autosize, soft-keyboard, flyout

I am working on a W8.1 App and have a big problem with the way a flyout is automatically repositioned when the soft-keyboard shows up:

I have created a demo that show how great the flyout positioning works:
http://1drv.ms/1kCgzMe

Scenario 1:

- Run the App in in the Simulator (or on device with soft-keyboard)
- Click on Item6. This will show a flyout **left** to the item.
- Focus the TextBox within the flyout to bring up the keyboard. The Flyout will be **centered** over the list (jump to the right) is resized to fit above the keyboard but it gets just about 2/3 of the available height.

**==> How to avoid the jumping and how to give the Flyout 100% of the available height?**

Scenario 2:

- Close the keyboard and the flyout to start over.
- Click on Item12. The Flyout will be placed above the item.
- Focus the TextBox and the Flyout will be moved up.

**==> TextBox is no longer visible**

Moving the focused TextBox off screen is really not a good idea when the user should be able to see what he is typing. Is there is good way to make the repositioning of the Flylout a little bit more clever?